# probability particle paths .two sets of parameters

Tags: st.statistics

Consider a paticle is going from a to b

At the first part of its journey is one set of mean and standard deviation for a normal distribution. Then it keeps going contingent upon a second normal distribution with a new set of parameters valid until the particle reaches its destination 'b'. What is the hybrid PDF for this particle based on this info? Or put the new PDF for getting from point a to b? I thought of using weighted variables in the new distribution.

Comment: Are you aware of http://stats.stackexchange.com?  As it stands, this.has two votes to close. Have a check of the faqs here to see if this question really fits here.